# How to manage build number with Firebase distribution?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, fastlane, cicd

Currently, I create my `ci/cd` for automate delivery app to my tester everytime that I pushed code to `git` via `firebase distribution` but I faced a problem about build number.

In firebase distribution, If I don't increase build number or version, it will not update app for distribute.

I have no idea how to auto increase build number every time I push code.

Has anyone ever done this ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

iOS:

```
   updated_build_num = increment_build_number(xcodeproj: your_xcodeproj_name)
```

[Details](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/#increment_build_number)

Android:

```
lane :bump_version_code do
  path = ENV["PWD"] + "/app/build.gradle"
  re = /versionCode\s+(\d+)/ 

  s = File.read(path)
  versionCode = s[re, 1].to_i
  s[re, 1] = (versionCode + 1).to_s

  f = File.new(path, 'w')
  f.write(s)
  f.close
end
```